# How to extract a value from a variable within if condition

Tags: perl, substr

I am trying to extract the timestamp portion from the variable, but somehow the substr function isnt working

This is what I have tried

```
while(<INFILE>){
chomp;
if(/timestamp:(.+$)/){
                        $ts = $1;
                        $ts =~ substr($ts, 10);
print $ts;
}

close(INFILE);
```

This is how the line is in the file

```
timestamp: 25JUN2019_02:55:02.234
somedata..
..
..
..

timestamp: 25JUN2019_07:00:28.718
```

I want the output to be

```
02:55:02.234
07:00:28.718
```

But instead the output is

```
25JUN2019_02:55:02.234
25JUN2019_07:00:28.718
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several issues:

1. You are using the bind operator `=~` instead of the assignment operator `=`
2. You should always `use strict` and `use warnings`
3. You should ignore whitespace before your match
4. If there is additional data on the line, `substr` will return it as well. You should scope your `substr` to only include want you want.

Revised code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while(<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  if (/timestamp:\s*(.+$)/) {
    my $ts = substr($1, 10, 12); # only include length of data you want
    print $ts;
  }
}

__DATA__
timestamp: 25JUN2019_02:55:02.234
```

Output:

```
02:55:02.234
```

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1. `=~` is the binding operator, you probably want normal assignment.
2. `substr $ts, 10` returns the substring form position 10 to the end of $ts. To only extract 12 characters, use

   ```
   $ts = substr $ts, 10, 12;
   ```

You can also extract the timestamp directly:

```
if(my ($ts) = /timestamp: [^_]+_(\S+)/){
    print $ts, "\n";
}
```